# Rpy2 could not find function

Tags: python, r, heatmap, rpy2

I've looked around for the error *could not find function "someFunction"* it appears to be a common error, however I have not found any pertaining to Rpy2.  I want to make a heat map from a matrix I made in python.

```
def HeatMap(HeatData):
    RHeatMap = robjects.FloatVector([HeatData[i] for i in range(len(HeatData[:,1]))])
    HeatMap = robjects.r['matrix'](RHeatMap, nrow = len(HeatData[:,1]))
    robjects.r('HeatMap = %s' %HeatMap.r_repr())
    robjects.r('jsr.colors=colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"),interpolate="linear")')
    robjects.r('heatmap(HeatMap, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col = topo.colors(100))')
```

The error is caused by both of the last 2 lines however in R I have no problem with either function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any problems with your code under Python2.7 and rpy2 2.1.9.

What happens if you call the R functions directly instead of using strings?

```
HeatMap = robjects.r['matrix'](RHeatMap, nrow = len(HeatData[:,1]))
robjects.r['heatmap'](HeatMap, Rowv = robjects.NA_Integer, Colv = robjects.NA_Integer, col = robjects.r['topo.colors'](100))
```

Comment: In R I can run both jsr.colors=colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"),interpolate="linear") and heatmap(HeatMap, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col = topo.colors(100)).  But I can not run those functions via Rpy2.